# How do you see the answers to your comment to someone's else thread in Threads?

Tags: threads

I posted a comment to someone else thread in Threads, and my comment says "4 answers, 3 likes", however, when I try to click my comment to see the answers to it, nothing happens.

How do you see the answers to your comment to someone's else thread in Threads?